# Giving a value between 0 and 15, return the right selection between 4 CheckBoxes

Tags: java, javafx, bit-manipulation

I am using this method to return a value between 0 and 15 depending on which ones of my 4 `CheckBox`es are selected by the user.

```
private int countSelectedCheck(CheckBox a, CheckBox b, CheckBox c, CheckBox d){
    CheckBox[] abcd = new CheckBox[]{a, b, c, d};
    // print binary
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < abcd.length; i++) {
        if (abcd[i].isSelected()) {
            value += (1 << i);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

I would like to do the inverse function, therefore to return a combination of selected/unselected between my 4 `CheckBox`es giving a value between 0 and 15. How can I achieve this in a efficient way, without repeating a lot of `if` statements or other not very efficient solutions?

Comment: @soufrk Did you read the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the mask, do bitwise and and check for `0`:

```
private void selectCheckBoxes(int value, CheckBox... array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i].setSelected((value & (1 << i)) != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow thanks, I still have to understand properly how those binary operations work!

Comment: BTW: In the original method the `+=` is a bit confusing. This is why I changed it to `|=` in the answer to the previous question. (Both do exactly the same in this case though).

Answer (score 2):

```
private static void checkSelected(int n, CheckBox... cbs)
{
    for (CheckBox cb : cbs)
    {
        if ((n & 1) == 1)
        {
            cb.setSelected(true);
        }
        n = n >> 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just do the inverse operation:

```
private static CheckBox[] getArray(int n) {
    CheckBox[] abcd = new CheckBox[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < abcd.length; i++) {
        if ((n &(1 << i)) != 0) {
           abcd[i].setValue(true); // set your checkBox as checked;
        }
    }
    return abcd;
}
```

What you do here is check the bits of your parameter. If the bit on position `i` is `1` then you set the checkbox as `checked`.

Comment: Thanks to you too, you are helping me understanding binary operations

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

```
import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class BinaryTest {
    private final Map<Checkbox, Integer> checkboxes = new HashMap<>();

    public BinaryTest(Checkbox... boxes) {
        int i = 1;
        for (Checkbox checkbox : boxes) {
            checkboxes.put(checkbox, i);
            i = i << 1;
        }
    }

    public int getValueOfCheckboxes() {
        int value = 0;
        for (Entry<Checkbox, Integer> entry : checkboxes.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().getState()) {
                value += entry.getValue();
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    public Set<Checkbox> getCheckboxesForValue(int value) {
        Set<Checkbox> boxes = new HashSet<>();
        for (Entry<Checkbox, Integer> entry : checkboxes.entrySet()) {
            if ((value & entry.getValue().intValue()) != 0) {
                boxes.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }

        return boxes;
    }
}
```

This should work for any number of Checkboxes. You put them into a map. The key of the map is the Checkbox and the value is the binary integer value.